# How can I disassociate "Esc" from "Exit full-screen view" in Safari?

Tags: macos, safari, keybindings

When I press `Esc` in Safari, it exits from full-screen mode.

There is another shortcut for that: `CTRL-CMD-F` and I'd rather keep only that one active.

Is it possible to disable the `Esc` keybinding?

I've looked at the *Keyboard shortcuts and gestures in Safari on Mac* page on the *Safari User Guide*. It says

> To turn off or change keyboard shortcuts, see *Create keyboard shortcuts for apps*. [A page on macOS user guide]

But the *Create keyboard shortcuts for apps* page explains how to *add* a keyboard shortcut in the macOS settings section `Apple menu  > System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts`.
Obviously, I could *remove* a setting if it was listed there, but the default settings are not available.

I thought of binding the `Esc` key with an undefined menu item, but in some contexts that keybinding executes actions that I'd keep configured as they are, ideally.

In particular, it will perform the following (as presented in the *Safari User Guide*):

> - "While typing in the Smart Search field, restore the current web page address"
> - "Close Reader"
> - "Cancel editing a bookmark name in the sidebar"

I've also tried inspecting the situation with CheatSheet. The app is really cool, it displays (almost) all the keyboard shortcuts for an app and allows to edit them via another app (not tested), but the "Esc" is not on the list so I guess it also can not be edited.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable Esc shortcut to quit Fullscreen](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110569/disable-esc-shortcut-to-quit-fullscreen)

Comment: No, they suggest to intercept and remap <kbd>Esc</kbd> using dedicated system utilities. But I don't want to disable it completely because the <kbd>Esc</kdb> is also used to ["While typing in the Smart Search field (to) restore the current web page address"](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/guide/safari/cpsh003/mac) and <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> does not work in that case.

Comment: Have you tried the [first](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/232543/383854) solution?

Comment: @TwlvSeconds yes. The first solution suggests two things. 1) bind the "Exit Full Screen" action to a different keybinding 2) promotes a paid, closed-source, software called "Keyboard Maestro" to "do the same thing". I used the trial version just to see how it looked but was too complex, anyway it makes no logical sense. Please, read again my comment. I want to unbind `Esc` => `Exit Full Screen` **and nothing else**.
On the bright side, I stumbled on a great open-source alternative to "Keyboard Maestro" called _Karabiner-Elements_, I love it!

Comment: @protoboolean how did you do it with Karabiner-Elements?

Comment: @EvanHammer I'm not 100% sure and since then I switched to _Linux Fedora_ as my daily driver, wiping the MacOS clean; so I can't check the Karabiner-Elements config. I reckon that I associated `Esc` to `Shift`+`Esc` for the Safari app only. Adding a modifier to `Esc` worked as a by-pass to the default action. Check the official docs for the details.