# how to prevent the escape key to move a window out of split view?

Tags: macos, multitasking

I often use split view, with some apps where I have to use the escape key within the app, several times in a row.

If I press the escape key too much it will move the active app out of split view.

This is extremely annoying. I search in the keyboard shortcuts settings, without luck.

How can I disable / modify this functionality?

This is on Mac OS Ventura 13.1.

Comment: Related: https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/110569/151404

Comment: Another question is in what app are you repeatedly pressing Esc?  If you have to press it so many times successively so often, it sound like there’s a bigger issue you’re trying to overcome.

Comment: @Allan several apps, but today.. Excel...

Comment: @Jballin I already searched this way but didn't manage to find how. SplitView is not an app. If you can details how to do it I would be grateful.

Comment: And this is on Excel for the iPad (I use it often)?  Can you give a scenario where you need press the Esc key successively and/or often?

Comment: @Allan this is not on iPad but on MacOS (edited the question , sorry forget to specify). In Excel sometimes you have to edit the content of the cell and to leave the edit mode you use escape. Sometimes you are *not* in edit mode but press escape as a reflex. Sometimes this is cause excel doesn't recognise a function, or to dismmiss an error message, etc...  Also for some other app like iTerm

Comment: You came from a Windows environment I take it?  Been there. I’d advise not changing the behavior because the Esc key does what you want when appropriate and does what it’s supposed to even when you didn’t intend to.  The problem comes in how is the OS to know the difference.  For me it was just re-learning the correct workflow

Comment: I also edited your tags - there really isn’t a split view tag as split view is a function of multitasking.

Comment: I respectfully disagree with you Allan. This is not an XY problem. I really want to change the behavior of this specific feature of Mac Os with this specific key, and as already told, excel is merely an example but not the sole one.
FWIW I do not come from a Windows env (I hate MS bullshit but have to work with it).
Also I didn't create the split view tag, it existed and has 50+ questions using it, but well, it doesn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced with the same issue.

To clarify, why "Esc" is needed in a browser: On some pages I use it many times without thinking, like on Home Assistant automation. There are many sub-windows created and these are closed most conveniently by tapping "Esc".

Unfortunately in split screen, they are not closed but the browser leaves the split screen (Firefox in my case).

Long answer short: I cannot use split screen. It is awkward to activate and left accidentally most times.

I arrange two windows next to each other and use "Esc" in the way it was meant.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).